# generate XML and save it to disk issue

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am getting the following error message when I generate the XML file and save it to the disk. I am getting "XML document must have a top level element". What could be the problem? I appreciate any help. If I use

```
echo sqlToXml($result, "SalesOrder", "sales");
```

the xml data shows in IE. But for some reason it throws an error when I try to save it.

```
     header("content-type:text/xml");
     $connection = mysql_connect( $db_host, $db_username, $db_password );
    if (!$connection){
    die ("Could not connect to the database: <br />". mysql_error());
    }
    // Select the database
    $db_select=mysql_select_db($db_database);
    if (!$db_select){
    die ("Could not select the database: <br />". mysql_error());
    }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from table1");

header("Content-Type: application/xml");
$xmlDocument1 = sqlToXml($result, "SalesOrder", "sales");
$filename= 'c:\\xmldoc\\results.xml';

file_put_contents($filename ,$xmlDocument1);

function sqlToXml($queryResult, $rootElementName, $childElementName)
{

$xmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" ?>\n"; 
$xmlData .= "<" . $rootElementName . ">";

while($record = mysql_fetch_object($queryResult))
{ 
    $xmlData .= "<" . $childElementName . ">";
    for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($queryResult); $i++)
    { 
        $fieldName = mysql_field_name($queryResult, $i); 
        $xmlData .= "<" . $fieldName . ">";
        if(!empty($record->$fieldName))
            $xmlData .= $record->$fieldName; 
        else
            $xmlData .= "null"; 

        $xmlData .= "</" . $fieldName . ">"; 
    } 
    $xmlData .= "</" . $childElementName . ">"; 
} 
$xmlData .= "</" . $rootElementName . ">"; 
}
```

Here is the result XML.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
  <SalesOrder>
    <Sales>
     <SalesOrderNumber>SO43</SalesOrderNumber>
     <PurchaseOrderNumber>PO18</PurchaseOrderNumber>
     <AccountNumber>3333</AccountNumber>
     <OrderDate>2001-07-01</OrderDate>
   </Sales>
  </SalesOrder>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you miss the **return** statement in your sqlToXml-Function?

```
    } 
    $xmlData .= "</" . $childElementName . ">"; 
  } 
  $xmlData .= "</" . $rootElementName . ">"; 
  return $xmlData;  
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have the return statement. But I am still getting "XML document must have a top level element" error message.

Comment: Can you paste the resulting xml document?

Comment: I pasted xml document. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Now I see 'An invalid character found in text content'